# inverted scrolling (natural) in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have set touch-pad-scrolling to inverted (natural) on my laptop. It works everywhere (pdf, browser, etc) but in vscode, which insists on normal scrolling. Going through the settings file of vscode didn't reveal an appropriate entry.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 22.04.2 with VS Code 1.83.0 installed as a Snap.

Answer (score 11):

You can try the trick in the settings:

```js
"editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": -1,
```

to flip the scroll direction.