# vscode: separate scrolling direction for trackpad and mouse?

Tags: visual-studio-code, scroll, direction

With the trackpad, I am used to inverted/natural scrolling.
With the mouse, I am used to direct scrolling.

I changed the scroll direction setting as mentioned in this previous post [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835562/inverted-scrolling-natural-in-vscode) but it sets both the trackpad and mouse wheel direction the same. I want them to be opposites.

This is not a problem with other apps in the system. I am running zorin os lite 16.3.

Can anyone help me on this matter?

Comment: The problem is specifically with vscode. My OS/DE has opposite scrolling directions for trackpad and mousewheel. sorry if that wasn't made clear